# Quantifying Onside Kick Variations

Tags: combinations

I work with a high school football team.  We have six (6) different methods/ways we can execute an onside kick (end-over-end, pop-up, jelly roll, copter, squib and drop-kick), five (5) directions we can kick it (far right, right, middle, left and far left), and we have five (5) different formations we can line up in.  Given those three (3) variables - 6 methods, 5 locations, 5 formations - what is the formula, or methodology, by which I can calculate the total quantity of possible combinations that we can use?  For example, we could go EOE (end-over-end)/far right/Formation 1, or drop-kick/far left/Formation 5, or . . .  I'm trying to find the total number of combinations.  (I'm not a math whiz, so feel free to dumb down the answer.)  THANK YOU!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product

Answer (score 1):

Note that events are mutually independent, as we can choose whichever option we want, not depending on the previous choice (eg. we can choose EOE and then we can choose all $5$ sides and after that all $5$ formations). So in case of mutually independent events we multiply all possibilities and we get that the total number of combinations is:

$$6 \times 5 \times 5 = 150 \text { combinations}$$